# JavaScript Convert Canvas To PGM

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, image-conversion, pgm

I am trying to convert canvas in JavaScript to pgm.
After i convert the file and download it to my desktop, it has the pgm extension, but when i open it with editor it is coded as png.
i think if JavaScript didn't recognize the extension that you want to convert to, it will convert it by default to png.
So JavaScript can convert to png, jpeg etc, but not to pgm ?

My question is it possible to convert canvas to pgm using JavaScript, if not is there any available plugin or Js library to do so.

```
function image_download() {
    canvas = $('#canvas').get(0);
    var image = new Image();
    image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/pgm");


    var download = document.createElement('a');
    download.href = image.src;
    download.download = 'map.pgm';
    download.click();
}
```

Comment: I didn't know this format at all, and I am sure most browsers don't provide an option to encode it natively, but, from what [I've read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netpbm_format) it shouldn't be too hard to convert the `[rgba]` bitmap array you get from [`getImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/getImageData) into PGM and PPM yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### PGM writer

To save a canvas as PGM I just went to http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/pgm.html which details the file format and used that information to create a function that converts a canvas to the PGM bin.

#### Conversion

The file has a header that describes the file and content and then a binary array of values, either 8 bit or 16bit

So start with the header and create it as a string

```
const CR = "\n";
var header = "P5" // required
header += CR; // add whitespace char
header += canvas.width;     
header += CR; // add whitespace char
header += canvas.height;     
header += CR; // add whitespace char
```

The header is not complete but we need to get the max value of the pixel values so will convert the image and find the max while at it.

So via the 2D context get the pixel data.

```
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.height);
```

You have several options on what data you want. The format specifies a logarithmic scale for some of the values and linear for others. I will leave it to you to find the conversion, if it is important to maintain gamma. (Note really only needed if you plan to broadcast, or preserve light values, eg astronomical images)

There is a utility to convert from linear to BT.709 gamma function. See linked doc

I have added some simple formats. Two are 16 bit with a max value of 3*255.

If you are converting from jpeg encoded images it is best to extract the brightness from the image by first converting the pixel RGB to HSL and saving only the L as a 8bit value this will stop the jpegs poor quality hue and saturation data effecting the result (jpeg has near lossless grey scale data)

```
const formats = {
    mean : {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++] = ((r + g + b) / 3 ) | 0 },
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint8Array(w * h) },
    },
    summed : {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++] = r + g + b },
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint16Array(w * h) },
    },
    meanLog : {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++]  = Math.sqrt((r * r + g * g + b * b)/ 3) | 0 },
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint8Array(w * h) },
    },
    summedLog : {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++] = Math.sqrt(r * r + g * g + b * b) | 0 },
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint16Array(w * h) },
    }
}
var imgData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,ctx.canvas.width,ctx.canvas.height);
var format = formats.mean;
var bin = format.dataStore(canvas.width, canvas.height);
var r,g,b,summed,mean,summedLog,meanLog;
var i = 0;
var j = 0;
var max = 0;
var d = imgData.data; // shorthand var to pixel data
while(i < d.length){
    format.convert(d[i++],d[i++],d[i++]);
    max = Math.max(bin[j-1],max);
    i++; // skip alpha
}
header += max;     // max value. 
header += CR; // add whitespace char
// We have all that is needed to create the file so first convert
// header string to ascII
var fileBin = new Uint8Array(header.length + bin.length);
for(i = 0; i < header.length; i++){
     fileBin[i] = header.charCodeAt(i) & 0b01111111; // strip of top bit just in case superstitious coder reads this
}
fileBin.set(new Uint8Array(bin.buffer),header.length); // add the pixel data

// fileBin is the 8bit bin of the PGM file
// Note transparent pixels are black.
// Note I do not check for all black. Format doc indicates that a max val in the head of zero is illegal. What that means you will have to find out.
```

And that is it. You can convert it to Base64 encoded, or just save it as is

Please note I never use this image format or heard of it before this answer and the above code is a quick interpretation of the document linked at the top of the answer. If it works, I dont know as I have nothing to test it on. The code is free of syntax and runtime errors.

It is more as a guide to show how to create a binary file for a specific format

#### Update

#### JPEG luminance preserve

I thought I would also add a format to handle JPEG images which just requires a good RGB to HSL function.

```
   // NOTE to prevent data loss the out put of lum has been
   // scaled from the normal 0-100 to 0-255 for the example PGM image format
   // If you use this function to get HSL values compatible with HSL CSS 
   // colours change the multipliers from 255 to 100. Commented with [*1]
   function rgb2hsl(r,g,b){ // integers in the range 0-255
        var minC, maxC, dif, h, l, s;
        h = l = s = 0;
        r /= 255;  // normalize channels
        g /= 255;
        b /= 255;
        min = Math.min(r, g, b);
        max = Math.max(r, g, b);
        if(min === max){  // [*1] no colour so early exit
            return {
                h, s,
                l : Math.floor(min * 255), // this normally is 0-100
            }
        }
        dif = max - min;
        l = (max + min) / 2;
        if (l > 0.5) { s = dif / (2 - max - min) }
        else { s = dif / (max + min) }
        if (max === r) {
            if (g < b) { h = (g - b) / dif + 6.0 }
            else { h = (g - b) / dif }                   
        } else if(max === g) { h = (b - r) / dif + 2.0 }
        else {h = (r - g) / dif + 4.0 }   
        h = Math.floor(h * 60);
        s = Math.floor(s * 100);
        l = Math.floor(l * 255); // [*1] this normally is 0-100
        return {h, s, l};
    },
```

Then add the following to the formats object

```
    formats.jpegLumPreserve = {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++] = rgb2hsl(r + g + b).l},
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint8Array(w * h) },
    }
```

If you are saving from images that are originally stored as jpeg (jpg) you should use this format

```
    format = formats.jpegLumPreserve;
```

#### Perceptual

As there is always some smart ah... person that needs to tout the perceptual luminance conversion I will add that as well because they generally get it wrong. As i think the conversion is some what of an old joke the conversion is based on the 2/7/1 rule and done in the logarithmic space.

```
    formats.perceptual = {
        convert (r, g, b) { bin[j++] = Math.sqrt(r * r * 0.2 + g * g * 0.7 + b * b * 0.1) | 0},
        dataStore (w, h) { return new Uint8Array(w * h) },
    }
```

This is base on the average adult humans ability to perceive the 3 primary colours red, green, and blue and match the grey (luminance) result to the perceived colour luminance.

Comment: Thank you, your answer helped me finding a good solution for this problem but with a different approach. (and sorry for my late reply)

Comment: I think this answer glosses over a few critical pieces.  Your canvas is going to be sRBG, in every case from my understanding.  There are a number of grayscale formulas one can apply depending on if you have converted them to linear or not (https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article/file?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0029740&type=printable -- Title: Color-to-Grayscale: Does the Method Matter in Image
Recognition?).  PGM requires 709 non-linear gamma compression to be legit, however the standard acknowledges many variants (es: linear rgb grayscale).